# how can I read multiple keys from localStorage with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am saving several keys in the localStorage with the following line

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhJ8U.png)

and I want to iterate them to display the products in a cart.
but I can't get it to show all the keys

```js
const arre = Object.keys(localStorage)

const recorreArray = (arr) => {
  for(let i=0; i <= arr.length; i++){
  console.log(arr[i]);
  }
}

const prueba = recorreArray(arre)
  

  const stringifiedProducts = localStorage.getItem(arre)
  const products = JSON.parse(stringifiedProducts)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first you need to make an object which have your all keys. and then set them to local storages instead of having different keys.

for example

```
 var myobj={
 "firstData":"data1",
 "secondData":"data2",
 "thirdData": "data3"
 }
```

now set this data to localStorage

```
 localStorage.setItem('MyObject', JSON.stringify(myobj));
```

now set this data From localStorage

```
 var AllKeysFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('MyObject');
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response. I am getting the keys from an api randomly, the idea is to be able to add a button that eliminates the key chosen by the user and not all together

Comment: Brother as I am also making the Ecommerce in Mean stack so my point is the same to get and delete and set local storages on the basis of user login then I got an advice from an expert that i need a temporary collection (table of db) and store the info and cart related to the user and then once it checout it should delete it. I think you should use db to do this process